# How to remove focus completely from the background activity after launching a popup activity

Tags: android

My app has an activity, say Activity_A which has a Floating Action Button (FAB). On clicking the FAB, an Intent is created and a new popup activity is launched over Activity_A, covering some part of it. The popup activity has an EditText view in it. When I click on it, the touch keyboard causes the background Activity_A to rise up instead of the popup activity.

What I need is, the background Activity_A should completely lose it focus until the popup activity is closed.

Also, can I dim the Activity_A while the popup activity is active? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself. Here's the solution if anyone else comes across this problem.

To block the background activity from panning up, add the line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to your activity attribute in the Manifest file.

To dim the backgroud activity, add the lines

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
 <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
 <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>` (**0.5** value can be adjusted)

to your activity's theme in @styles

**I haven't yet got the solution to pan the popup activity window when touch keyboard is activated.** Simply adding the `android:windowSoftInputMode` doesn't work for it.